# Bottle's request.get_cookie("cookie-name") works on all browsers but returns None on Firefox

Tags: python, bottle

I'm working on a pymon game code. When a new game is created, players can join. When a player hits a "Join" button (implemented with react), an ajax request is sent to "games//players" which extracts the player name from the cookie and adds it to the game table in a MySql DB. This works fine in all browsers, but on Firefox for some reason, the result from reading the player cookie is "None"

I've checked the cookies on my Firefox browser and they include the "player" cookie with the correct player name. I also checked the path of the cookie and it's "/", which means it should also be fine. I don't understand what could possibly go wrong that the same code works fine for all other browsers except for firefox. Here's my code:

```
@app.post('/games/<game_id>/players') 
def joinGameHandler(game_id): 
    playerName = request.get_cookie("player") 
    print(playerName) 
    result = controller.joinGame(game_id, playerName) 
    return utils.jsonResponse(response, {"result":result})
```

In all browsers, the code works fine and playerName returns the player name. On Firefox however, this variable returns None.

Comment: It seems to me that you should start investigating this on the client side. Using the developer tools in Firefox/other browsers, and the javascript console: does the React code give errors or different result on firefox compared to other browsers? Are the cookies actually set in the browser?

Comment: The cookie is set on the browser but the python code request.get_cookie returns None

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding credentials: 'include' to the options in Fetch like so:

fetch(url, { method: 'POST', credentials: 'include'})

The problem was cross-domain issues: the fetch url didn't match the url from which the fetch script was called. For users privacy, Firefox doesn't include cookies in the request in such cases, hence request.get_cookie was empty and returned None.